# Perforce Change List too Big

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, I have created a change list that has over 200,000 files (by doing a rename on a directory).  This change list is now too big to submit or revert.  When I try, I get an error saying that the operation took too long.

I am now stuck with this change list that has my original directory in marked for delete state and a new directory that hasn't been submitted.  Is there a way undo this change list?

Comment: You could ask the perforce support for help.

Comment: What, exactly, is the "took too long" message. Depending on that message, your administrator can reconfigure the server to allow this rename to complete. It would be preferable to adjust the configuration, temporarily, to complete your desired change, then having to submit multiple smaller changelists.

Comment: The exact error is "Operation took too long".  Word for word, that is what perforce reports.
It is from the Perforce system setting "MaxLockTime" (See: http://kb.perforce.com/AdminTasks/PerformanceTuning/MaximizingPe..Performance).
Our Sys Admins purposely set it to 60 sec to stop long running operations.  They don't want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert the files a few at a time. As a test, you could run `p4 revert //path/to/some/file` and verify that it's able to revert that file.

Once you know that's working, you just need a way to automate the process.

You could script something up that starts in the root directory and runs through all directories breadth-first, running `p4 revert //path/to/folder/*` at each folder (I think you could also use client paths).

Answer (score 0):

You can revert via the command line using the p4 tool. I do not think you can revert the files from the UI. The associated documentation shows various examples of how revert all or specific files (see the Examples section):

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/revert.html